# How to remove color dye stain from colored clothes?

Tags: cleaning, clothing

Mostly the dye stains are removed by bleaches which include chlorine that removes the stain.

But this only works with white clothes because it damages colored clothes.

How can I remove colored dye stain from colored clothes without destroying the original color of the clothes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several products on the market that will remove colors from white or light clothing that came from another darker/brighter colored piece of clothing washed with it or from clothing that was previously dyed and bled on your whites from washing together.  One is Carbona color remover and another is Rit color remover.  (Rit is actually the company that creates clothing dye, so you may try their product because they’ve been around for years, and they have probably heard every color problem that has come up.)

I understand that if you dye clothing, doing a final rinse in white vinegar is supposed to set the dye.  Google this though as I have only heard of it in conversation so not sure of results.

Good luck!

Judy